Windows asking for app when plugging in power cable
Whenever I plug my laptop into a wall port (USB-C to USB-C), it asks me to pick an app

Does anyone know how I can stop it from asking this? Clearly no app is actually needed, the Watts flow into the computer just fine if I press the escape key at this point.
(Windows 11 Pro, Dell laptop, USB-C cable made by "Ocetea" whoever they are.

Might be https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/get-an-app-to-open-this-dpmcentennial-link/4bb3d23f-e945-4793-a644-c2b3bc0920c5, but you do not state make (or model). Edit question.


Whenever I plug my laptop into a wall port (USB-C to USB-C), it asks me to pick an app

Uninstalling both Dell Update and Dell Assistant and DELL Command should resolve this issue. I would also recommend uninstalling Dell Update and the Dell Support Assist applications.
Your issue is caused by a misbehaving Dell application that is absolutely not required for your system to function.

Dell Update can be handy, but I agree that it is not necessary. I would uninstall Command and assistant but just make sure Dell Update is updated fully itself, or uninstall it and reinstall it, and see if the issue is gone.

@music2myear - I can be reinstalled. It probably won’t cause the problem if reinstalled, but as I don’t have access to a system where I can install and try to reproduce the software problem, my only recommendation is to uninstall it.
